# column width of gridview increasing with paging numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

*- first column width is increasing with paging numbers in grid view

   width of column 1 is increasing with page numbers  how to remove
   extra white space in column 1
 - kindly tell me how to fix paging problem, where i have to change to fix page size problem?*

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GrdKeyWord" SkinID="gridviewSkin" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
        OnRowCommand="GrdKeyWord_RowCommand" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdKeyWord_RowCancelingEdit"  AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" OnPageIndexChanged="OnPageChanged" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="20" PageSize="10" >
           <PagerStyle CssClass="gridViewPager" Font-Underline="false" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0"  />

        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Assign To
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>

                     <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddUserId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Gv_DdlUserName" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Projectname" HeaderText="Project Name" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Keyword
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("KeywordID") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Keyword" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KeyWord") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Start Date
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_StartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjAssignDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Target Date
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_TargetDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TargetDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Exp Position
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Position" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PositionExp") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Today's pos
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_TodayPos" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CurrentPosition") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Change" Text="Change" ForeColor="#4377A8" Font-Bold="true" runat="server"
                        CommandName="Change" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'/>


                    <asp:Button ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ForeColor="Maroon" Font-Bold="true" runat="server"
                        CommandName="Cancel" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' Visible="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: try set width in itemtemplate ?

Comment: use a databound event or read this example
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e1ae25/how-to-remove-nbsp-from-the-gridview-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: <HeaderStyle  Width="70px" />

                            <ItemStyle Width="70px" />

i tried this but width not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing

```
 <PagerStyle CssClass="gridViewPager" Font-Underline="false" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0"  />
```

or add

`max-width` property to your `gridViewPager` css class.

Comment: i have removed pager style , and it solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Gridview renders the Pager as an additional Row in the Gridview.  It is a row with a single `td` entry whose `colspan` is adjusted by the GridView control as neccessary.  The Pager is actually an embedded table:

```
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
      <tr><th scope="col">column header 1</th><th scope="col">column header 2</th></tr>
      <tr><td>1002</td><td>0</td></tr>

      <!-- Begin Pager Row of Gridview -->
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <!-- colspan will adjust accordingly -->
          <table>  
            <tbody>
              <tr> 
                <td><span>1</span></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Page$2')">2</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Page$3')">3</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Based on your Gridview, and If i counted correctly, your pager row should have a `colspan` of 8.

What does the rendered html look like? Are you doing any jquery or JS manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by CSS. Add this code:

```
.gridViewPager {display: contents;}
```